# How to check the post method in postman from an array

Tags: postman

How can i send this data using post method in postman?

```
["name": "fenna", "question": [["answer": "Yes, always", "question": "45"], ["answer": "Very satisfied", "question": "46"], ["answer": "Very easy", "question": "47"]]]
```

This is the data which i need to post it.But how to i give in the json in postman?

Comment: how to check in postman

Comment: In Postman, add header 'Content-Type' with a value of 'application/json'. Set the URL to the endpoint, select POST, copy your json into the 'Body' and click Send.

Comment: This feels like a non-question. By simply reading the Postman documentation on how to use the application, would have told you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like this -

[image: screenshot]

Text (Copy paste this body -> raw) -

```
{
        "name": "fenna",
        "question": [
            {
                "answer": "Yes, always",
                "question": "45"
            },
            {
                "answer": "Very satisfied",
                "question": "46"
            }, 
            {
                "answer": "Very easy",
                "question": "47"
            }
        ]


}
```